# How to Stop camera to be used . or how to make it unusable

Tags: android

I am working on  an app, in which i need to stop some functionality of phone,

which include :

1) making or receiving phone calls,

2) use of Bluetooth or wifi,

3) Use of camera,

these feature will lock as soon as this app get installed, and will be locked until the get uninstalled, first two i have done, but i dont know how to achieve 3rd task, as i have tried locking the camera with my app, but after some time it automatically unlocked.

any clue/pointer/help will be appreaciated. Thanks

Comment: Does this app take your phone hostage and demands money to unlock those features?

Comment: Off Topic and Just curious: Why would you want to do something like this? And why would anybody install your app if you disable parts of their phone?

Comment: @ArjunShankar: I'm guessing this is an app for some corporate device.  His company may want to give employees Android devices, but don't want them to use it for play toys or maybe needs these things disabled for security reasons.  Since no (decent) Android device exists that don't have cameras, bluetooth, wifi, or make calls, they have to put on some security app to disable them.  I can see at least that as a valid reason for it to exist.  Whether or not it's possible is another matter.

Comment: @ Oli and Arjun
it is a client app and they required that functionality. there are 40 other such feature, most of them i done.
the feature will not be blocked all the time, one can enable these feature from server. long story. dont wanna disclose much .:) 
@ Sergei : lol

Comment: @ DeeV .. Exactly You take it right. its a app which have 40 such features, which even include User can not use different sim card, or can not use the Internet  within the company premises.

Comment: In this case guys (in case of corporate device), I would suggest just uninstall some core APK's which handle networking and camera usage... Or better to compile special ROM with disabled features

Comment: i am a app developer, I can not modify the OS and flash devices with my binaries. :) Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to register broadcast receiver for BOOT_COMPLETE event,  and  open camera device[s] and lock() it  - nobody will be able to use it until lock is given up.  And I think it will stay even after your process is killed ( not sure though)

You may also  try to FUBAR camera with some weird settings (I managed this sometimes, though can not explain how. - camera was unusable until reboot)

Comment: I tried locking the Camera with my app, but after some duration, the camera can be used normally, don't know what make it unlocked.

Comment: you can do it periodically. do you need this for single device, or different ones?

Comment: it should support as much devices as possible. Seriously i tried lots of thing on this idea of locking camera with my app instance.. but could not succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

To stop camera usage I would suggest to intercept `Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON` broadcast and just `abortBroadcast()` - in this case camera usage will be blocked.

The same approach I believe can be used for wifi and bluetooth, though I didn't check it.

**Update** for sure phone usage can be handled in the same manner.

Comment: this will work only if hardware camera button is pressed. (not universally available)

Comment: Tried this long back will work only if camera button pressed,not if directly used by camera app or other app, but as so many Smartphones(Samsung galaxy lower end) do not have camera button. they need to go to camera app and use camera. it wont work in that case.